# Java Tank game, creating the fire method

Tags: java, class, methods

I am writing a program that pits two tanks against each other. I have written all the methods except the fire that would end the game. So far

```
public class Tank {
    Tank() {
        int xPos, yPos;
        char direction;
        boolean loaded = 0;
    }

    public void move(Tank currentPlayer) {
        if (yPos<=4 && yPos>=0) {
            if (xPos<=4 && xPos>=0) {
                if (currentPlayer.direction == 'u') {
                    currentPlayer.yPos--;
                }
                if (currentPlayer.direction == 'd') {
                    currentPlayer.yPos++;
                }
                if (currentPlayer.direction == 'l') {
                    currentPlayer.xPos--;
                }
                if (currentPlayer.direction == 'r') {
                    currentPlayer.xPos++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void turn(boolean bool, Tank currentPlayer) {
        if (currentPlayer.direction == 'u') {
            currentPlayer.direction ='r';
        }
        if (currentPlayer.direction == 'd') {
            currentPlayer.direction = 'l';
        }
        if (currentPlayer.direction == 'l') {
            currentPlayer.direction ='u';
        }
        if (currentPlayer.direction == 'r') {
            currentPlayer.direction ='d';
        }
    }

    public void load(Tank currentPlayer) {
        currentPlayer.loaded=true;
    }

    public int fire(Tank currentPlayer, Tank jim) {
        // ???
    }    
}
```

How do I go about finishing my program? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does fire do? Does it immediately end the game? Does it fire a projectile?

Comment: How do you determine if the shot hit the other tank? If it does, end the game.

Comment: if the tank fires and hits the other tank then, yes, it is game over. I just am not sure how to check the other's position. This is a little too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a getter for the x-position, the y-position, and the current orientation of the tank. For example:

```
public int getX();
public int getY();
public char getOrientation();
```

By calling these methods, you should get the x position, y position, and orientation of the tank. Then to check a hit. You know what direction you're facing. So if you're facing up, see if the other tank is on the same x as you, and that their y is above yours.

```
int otherX = jim.getX();
int otherY = jim.getY();

switch (currentPlayer.getOrientation())
{
    case 'u':
        //Check if you're in same x
        //Check if above player
        break;
    case ... etc.
}
```

Then in the case of a hit, in other words if the conditions are met. The game should end with the currentPlayer victorious.